# Session on iis7

Tags: php, session, iis-7

I have setup an iis7 server and installed php on it and changed my session folder from TEMP to php/session. Session is working as intended i tought until i moved my login script from my local php server(wamp) to iis7. My script wont pass `$_session` to global.php (db connection and inlogg check) from my login page. It will pass `$_session` to next page im sending my header to. Script is 100% working on wamp server.

Global.php

```
//Connect stuff
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$logged=1;
}else{
$logged=0;
}
```

Login.php

```
include_once("global.php")  
//working prepare and $login_check = query
while($row =sqlsrv_fetch_array($login_check, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
$id = $row['id'];
}

$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;

header("location:admin_page.php");
```

if i do `var_dump` on admin_page `$_SESSION['username']` it will return back with a string but global.php will return false on `$_session` these 3 files are in the same folder.